# How can i exclude ActionBar when transitions between Activities on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-transition, shared-element-transition

On Android 5.0 Lollipop,

I have two activities A and B.  Activity B has a slie enter transition from bottom with a Overlay ActionBar, but when B shows, the ActionBar also slide from bottom to top.

How can i prevent the actionbar from slide transition. does system actionbar has an id that i can add to the exclude target ?

thanks!

Comment: Consider using the Toolbar, introduced in Lollipop, for more flexibility with the header.

Comment: Since you are using window animations it is applied to actionbar as well. I would suggest using a fragment and animating it from bottom up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the AppCompat v7 library, it is easy:

```
View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
int actionBarId = R.id.action_bar_container;
enterTransition.excludeTarget(decor.findViewById(actionBarId), true);
```

Unfortunately, the action bar container view ID is not part of the public API, so if you are not using the AppCompat v7 library (i.e. you are using the official framework libraries) you will need to work around this by using the following code to retrieve the ID instead:

```
int actionBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
```

Note that this code will break if the action bar container's ID name changes in a future version of Android. I doubt it will ever change though...

See [this post](https://plus.google.com/+AlexLockwood/posts/RPtwZ5nNebb) for some other related information.

Comment: What is slideTransition?

Comment: I've renamed `slideTransition` to `enterTransition` in my answer. The reason why I called it `slideTransition` was because the OP asked about how to implement a slide-up enter transition.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify this type of constraint in the xml way?

Comment: @avalactus If you are using the AppCompat v7 library, I believe you could exclude the action bar by adding `<targets><target android:excludeId="@id/action_bar_container"/></targets>` to your transition's XML.

Comment: This isn't working for me!  I have AppCompat v7 enabled, and I followed the instructions verbatim, but the toolbar is still animating.

Comment: Google+ Post Link is expired.

Answer (score 6):

My solution is to extend the style with this args:

```
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/slide</item>
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/slide</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/enter</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@transition/enter</item>
```

This here is my **`res/transition/slide.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:slideEdge="bottom">
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
    </targets>
</slide>
```

This here is my **`res/transition/enter.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:targetSdkVersion="19"
    android:transitionOrdering="sequential">
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@id/action_bar_container"/>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
    </targets>
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
    <changeClipBounds/>
    <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

You can play around with that transitions as you like, important is just those excluded targets.

Comment: Perhaps this would work better if there were 2 slide transitions, one for enter and one for exit - sliding in opposite directions. That helped me.