# How to create slide transition animation between two android activities and exclude toolbar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar, shared-element-transition

I have two android activities with same toolbar, How can I slide between activities and exclude toolbar?
I've searched google and stackoverflow, it seems these two similar questions has accepted answer but I'm new to android and need more help.

[How can i exclude ActionBar when transitions between Activities on Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658577/how-can-i-exclude-actionbar-when-transitions-between-activities-on-android-5-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Activity transition ignoring Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461510/activity-transition-ignoring-toolbar)

Comment: why dont u just use fragment

Comment: actually in my app there will be more than 100 activities with same animation , can I use 100 fragments in one activity?

Comment: yes. and it's works much better than using 100 activities.

Comment: do these 100 fragments all get into memory at once or just one of them at any given time?

Comment: if you use them right. one at a time

Comment: because if all of them get to memory together, I'm afraid make performance issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195388/discussion-between-lvl4fi4-and-john-sadeghi).