# Exclude BottomNavigation from Transition Animations in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I've been searching all around but I can't find an answer that helps solve this particular problem.
My application has a custom slide-in, slide-out effect used like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_right_out);
```

## The Problem

The problem is I have a BottomNavigation included in all activities, and I don't want it to get animated, I want to exclude it.

[image]

## What I'm trying to achieve

I want to exclude the Bottom Navigation from the animation. Or, in other words, how can I only animate the content between transitions?

[image]

EDIT: I already tried doing with Shared Element, but I wanted it to work below API 21.

Comment: Maybe you do an shared element transition with it ? did this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658577/how-can-i-exclude-actionbar-when-transitions-between-activities-on-android-5-0

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include I also wanted it to work below API 21. At least, in API 17.

Comment: @ChristophMayr Since I'm using animations with overridePendingTransition, how can I call the method `excludeTarget(findViewById(bottomNavId), true);` ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to exclude components form `overridePendingTransition()` API. Instead, you have to move to [Transitions API](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html). Particularly, this is [`Slide`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Slide.html) transition animation, where you exclude your bottom navigation view.

```
Transition slide = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
slide.excludeTarget(bottomNavigationView, true);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
```

See detailed implementation [here](http://xmodulo.com/activity-transition-animations-android.html).

You can see [support transition package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/package-summary.html) which backports Transitions API functionality upto API 14. But I couldn't find `Slide` transition in the classes list. Otherwise you can use [`TransitionEverywhere`](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere).