# How to exclude AppBar from page transition animations?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation, flutter-appbar

I want the AppBar in a Scaffold to remain static (at least graphically) while page transitions are animated *(like described [in flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation))*.

There's a similar question which shows what I mean, but for bottom navigation on native Android: [Exclude BottomNavigation from Transition Animations in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433249/exclude-bottomnavigation-from-transition-animations-in-android).

Comment: You can do a custom animation or Hero animation. That's the only case when transforming and "keeping" the AppBar is acceptable... if not, I don't see why you want to achieve that animation as it's not something users are use to.